# Are there ways to make pattern lab rebuild quicker (with node)?

Tags: patternlab.io

For every change I make I need to wait for the files to rebuild. The built takes 80ms to 1.30 minutes.

Is there a way to speed this up?

Are there any dos and don'ts or is this how long it takes no matter what.

I know might be due to many template render request (`{{> these}}`) but still 1.30 minutes is too long to make any real progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintainer of Pattern Lab Node here.

There is an experimental pull request in the works right now that will incrementally build only parts of a pattern tree. Only the changed patterns. It's not completely done yet nor hit the easier consumption methods, but the pull request is here: https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/pull/546

To play with it, clone or fork [Pattern Lab Node Core](https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node) and then [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) it with your edition.

Then pull down the branch.

```
git checkout -b headissue-540-build-changed-patterns-only dev
git pull https://github.com/headissue/patternlab-node.git 540-build-changed-patterns-only
```

This is getting into pretty advanced territory, and I make no promises about its reliability - but early testing from some users was positive. If nothing else, know that performance improvements are on the horizon!

**Update** The functionality mentioned above is now released in the core package. Read about it on the wiki: https://github.com/pattern-lab/patternlab-node/wiki/Incremental-Builds